# изменяющееся значение параметра в Post запросе

Tags: java, http, post

Здравствуйте, на сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии отправляется `Post` запрос.
При попытки составления такого запроса я обнаружил, что есть параметр который всегда меняется, можно ли отследить откуда берется значение параметра?
Можно ли в браузере посмотреть как он генерирует этот параметр?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно вы можете это сделать. Через средства разработки. Вы можете посмотреть код страницы, найти форму которая отправляется, значения input, или код JavaScript который задает это значение.